# Closed points on a curve correspond to places on the function field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, valuation-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth (integral) projective curve over a field $k$ and let $K$ be the function field of $X$.

> I'd like to prove that there is a bijective correspondence between the
>   closed points of $X$ and the set of places (i.e. equivalent absolute
>   values on $K$) which are trivial on $k$.

Clearly for every closed point $p$ I have the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,p}$ which is a DVR, therefore I get a desired valuation on $K$, hence a metric.

But what about the inverse of this map? From an absolute value of $K$ I want to get a closed point of $X$ inverting the above construction.

Comment: Do you know the valuative criteria for properness? This gives you, essentially, what you want.

Comment: I don't know it, I'll check this notion. Thank you.

Comment: How do I apply the criteria of properness to my problem?

Comment: You have a valuation  $v$ on $K$. This corresponds to a valuation subring $\mathcal{O}_v\subseteq K$. Note then that, in particular you know that we have the diagram

$$\begin{matrix}\text{Spec}(K) & \xrightarrow{i} & X\\ \downarrow &  &\downarrow\\ \text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}) & \to & \text{Spec}(k)\end{matrix}$$

Where the map $i$ is the inclusion of the spectrum of the function field into $X$ (i.e. it's the inclusion of the generic point). Note that we are using that $v(k^\times)=0$ to say that this diagram commutes (why?). So, by the valuative criteria for properness this

Comment: gives us an extension $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O})\to X$. Suppose that the closed point of $\mathcal{O}$ maps to the closed point $x$ of $X$. I claim then that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\mathcal{O}$ showing that $v=v_x$. But, this follows since the map $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\to\mathcal{O}$ is local (why?) and DVRs are maximal by domination amongst subrings of $K$. Thus, this implies that $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Why does the valuation being 0 on $k$ force the diagram to commute? We see it forces $k$ to inject into $\mathcal O$, but why into the ring of global functions on $X$?

Comment: One has to say also that an absolute value trivial on $k$ is necessarily non-archimedean, so it corresponds to a valuation.

Answer (score 1):

Valuations are the same as places, which are just maps from a valuation ring into its quotient field. The center of a place is the prime ideal of all functions on which the place is zero. In the case of a curve this will be a maximal ideal, and if the field is algebraically closed you get a point of the curve. This theory is exposited in Zariski and Samuel: Commutative Algebra Vol.II. In general many places will correspond to a given point, but if the point is simple there will be only one place for that point.

Comment: Well, as the OP mentioned, you need to assume that the kernel of the valuation contains the field of constants.

Comment: I am assuming this.

Comment: So, I took a look to Zariski&Samuel book. The chapter on valuations is huge!
By the way I have two comments/questions:
1) By the term "place" I refer to the definition you find in Neukirch ANT (ch.3). But I suppose that the two notions are the same.
2)  Is the result true if I don't assume $k$ to be algebraically closed?

Comment: If $k$ is not closed, cant you just take the ideal for an algebraic point and use that to define a valuation ?