# Notes on global function fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, arithmetic-geometry, function-fields

Does anyone happen to know a good set of notes on global function fields? In particular, I'm hoping to find something akin to Neukirch's chapter on Riemann-Roch theory, but for global function fields rather than number fields. If it helps, I think it relates to understanding [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3398360) - i.e. I need to understand more about the places above $\infty$.

Comment: My first suggestion would be Michael Rosen's *Number Theory in Function Fields* (Springer, GTM 210). Not sure it is what you want, though.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen From the contents page of the book I think it's not looking at the geometric side too much. I'm not sure if this is helpful, but I wanted to understand why a) the closed points of an elliptic curve E over $\mathbb{F}_p$ correspond to places on $\mathbb{F}_p(E)$, and b) actually calculating $\mathbb{F}_p(E)$ from the geometry of the curve. I'm not sure if this is reasonable though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is it about places above $\infty$ in a finite extension of $K(x)$ compared to places above some other place in $K(x)$ (all of them being trivial on $K$) that you feel you need to understand better?  If you are having trouble regarding the place at $\infty$ on $K(x)$ as being on the same footing as the other places on $K(x)$, think about how the linear fractional transformations of $K(x)$ like $x \mapsto 1/x$ or $x \mapsto x/(x+1)$ permute the places on $K(x)$ with residue field degree $1$ over $K$.

Can you think about places (including ramification and residue field extensions) in a more local way, not relying on the crutch of some global ring such as $K[x]$ in $K(x)$?
If $E/F$ is a finite extension of fields, a place (discrete valuation) $v$ on $F$ extends to finitely many places of $E$, and in terms of prime ideals this can be studied with the local ring $\mathcal O_v$ inside $F$ and prime ideals in the integral closure of $\mathcal O_v$ inside $E$.

Maybe some references on the MSE pages [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12717/points-and-dvrs) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036654/closed-points-on-a-curve-correspond-to-places-on-the-function-field) would be helpful.

Comment: You're right, I think the transformations are where I got lost before and need to examine again. Thank you for the links, they're very helpful.